# Why doesn't the query string appear in PHP-FPM status page?

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I've enable the PHP-FPM status page and reconfigured `nginx` to display it. The website in question is a drupal website where the URL gets rewritten such that all non-existing files get their URL rewritten to be `/index.php?q=<whatever>` If I access the status page itself with `?full` I can see that query string show up in the process list but when I navigate to a page on the site I would expect to see something similar to the above but instead get:

```
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           14/Dec/2017:17:06:53 -0500
start since:          16631
accepted conn:        26
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       2
active processes:     1
total processes:      3
max active processes: 2
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0

************************
pid:                  65
state:                Idle
start time:           14/Dec/2017:17:06:53 -0500
start since:          16631
requests:             9
request duration:     347524
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/html/index.php
last request cpu:     92.08
last request memory:  10485760

************************
pid:                  66
state:                Running
start time:           14/Dec/2017:17:06:53 -0500
start since:          16631
requests:             9
request duration:     211
request method:       GET
request URI:          /status?full
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               -
last request cpu:     0.00
last request memory:  0

************************
pid:                  8924
state:                Idle
start time:           14/Dec/2017:21:41:04 -0500
start since:          180
requests:             8
request duration:     349676
request method:       GET
request URI:          /index.php
content length:       0
user:                 -
script:               /var/www/html/index.php
last request cpu:     85.79
last request memory:  35651584
```

Is there a way to get the query string to survive the re-write or is there another tool for figuring out what PHP request specifically might be consuming CPU time? I'm basically trying to be able to track a CPU-consuming PID to a particular request if I need to do so for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Show nginx config

Comment: [conf.d/default.conf](https://dpaste.de/uwnH) and [nginx.conf](https://dpaste.de/Znko)

Comment: Why don't you just use your PHP error / access log files in conjunction with Nginx log files to track down this problem?

Comment: Because that wouldn't tell me which script on the production site is taking up the CPU. All I can see in `top` is there's some PHP script taking up the CPU and the access logs would only tell me which one if there just happened to be only one request around that time period. The status page gives me the PID associated with each request but in this case it's cutting off the full request (probably due to the URL re-write).

Comment: Get a list of the pages from access.log and hand it to the developer?

Comment: I'm trying to get to where I can trace an HTTP request back to a CPU consumer which would give me something intelligible to tell the developer. If an access log doesn't help me trace it back they probably aren't going to be able to either.